# Setting up MACVLAN - Ubuntu Server and a Repotect RP1008W Web Smart Swtich

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ping, switch, vlan

I have a big problem - my ISP won't let me do IP Aliasing, and will use only DHCP to assign statically IP's, so I have to resort to MACVLAN to set up multiple virtual interfaces, each with its own hardware address and the ISP will happily throw IP's at them.

I also bought a Web Smart Switch, hoping that it will be able to handle the VLAN tagged by the OS packets.

Switch is Repotec RP1008W.
PC is running Ubuntu 16.04 Server.

Problem is I can't ping the IP assigned to the MACVLAN interface macvlan0.

The PC has Internet connectivity, can ping and responds to ping on the physical eno1 interface. All websites located on the PC run fine.

Here is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
hwaddress ether 70:F3:95:0E:13:8A

# Second IP address, we need to set the MAC as well for DHCP to work.
iface macvlan0 inet dhcp
pre-up ip link add macvlan0 link eno1 type macvlan mode bridge
hwaddress ether 60:F3:95:0E:13:8A
auto macvlan0
```

Here is the configuration of the SWITCH:
Port 1 is where the Internet comes from.
Port 8 is where the PC is at

[vlanmode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGYHP.png)
[vlanmembers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V09Qt.png)

Comment: Well sorry to tell you this, but macvlan has not much to do with VLAN, and no 802.1q VLAN tagged packet is emitted unless you use `ip link add ... type vlan` (not macvlan), and I don't think you need vlan . macvlan is usually meant to be used by a container or VM (macvtap), or you'll have trouble with only one network stack to manage multihoming. This might still be able to do what you want if you disable rp_filter (reverse path filtering) for all and macvlan0. Anyway consider running the other IP from a container (which won't be easy to reach from the host, that's specific to macvlan)